# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $6\times6$ matrix by relabelling variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a system $\dot{\vec{x}}=A\vec{x}$ where

$A= \begin{pmatrix} -5&-1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&-5&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&3&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-1&0&4 \\ 0&0&-1&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&-3 \end{pmatrix}$

I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and I have to do it by relabelling the variables $x_i$. But I am confused about how to even make a start on this. I have looked at other questions on here and most are to do with doing it by inspection.

Comment: Sounds like they want you to diagonalize the matrix or something.

Comment: Consider first the $2\times 2$ block and relabel $x_1$ and $x_2$. After this, take the remaining $4\times 4$-block.

Comment: Note the checker board pattern in the lower $4×4$-block, so change the order to $x_3,x_5,x_4,x_6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, note that A can be written as A=\begin{pmatrix}B&0\\0&C\\\end{pmatrix}
when B=\begin{pmatrix}-5&-1\\1&-5\\ \end{pmatrix} and C=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&4\\-1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&-3 \end{pmatrix}
therefore, if we'll find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of each of the blocks, we are done.

At first, lets find the characteristic polynomials:
$p_B(x)=x^2+10x+26, p_C(x)=x^4-13x^2+20x-4$
the roots of the polynomials are $x=-5-i,-5+i$  and   $x=2,-\sqrt{5}-2,\sqrt{5}-2$
and as we mentioned before, these are the eigenvalues too.

now, for each eigenvalue  $x$ we need to find basis to $Null(M-xI)$ when $M$ is the block of the eigenvalue.
for example, if $x=-5+i$ :

$Null(B-(-5+i)I)=Null\begin{pmatrix}-i&-1\\1&-i\\ \end{pmatrix}=span\{\begin{pmatrix}i\\1\\ \end{pmatrix}\}$

and we get that $\begin{pmatrix}i\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$
is an eigenvector.

in the end, after some algebra we get that $\begin{pmatrix}i\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}-i\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\-1\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\-\sqrt{5} +1\\0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\sqrt{5} +1\\0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

are the eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $-5+i, -5-i, 2, -\sqrt{5}-2, \sqrt{5}-2$.